# What's the common ancestor of visual elements in C#?

Tags: c#, controls

I have a hard time believing that there isn't an answer here but it certainly looks like it doesn't exist.

I am trying to iterate over everything on the form and set the visible and enabled properties based on the tag value.  I find the reek of an absolutely duplicated routine between the routine iterating the controls and the routine iterating the menus--while both classes have visible, enabled and tag properties they appear to be separate items.

As far as I can tell the tree only converges at Component--but this lacks the visual properties.

Comment: Are you referring to WinForms, WebForms or WPF?

Comment: @Foole: Guessing WinForms as he referenced `Tag` which is only present in the WinForms control structure.

Comment: @Aren, indeed I think it's Windows Forms, but because Component is the common ancestor. WPF controls do have a Tag property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct, there is no common ancestor.  The ToolStripMenuItem class is derived from ToolStripItem, the base class for many derived classes that are parts of a MenuStrip or a ToolStrip.  They are special because they are not derived from Control.  They are window-less controls, they don't have a Handle property.  Which is the key property of the Control base class.

This is an optimization, the Control derived classes are expensive.  They need a native Windows window, a heavy operating system object with lots of overhead.  Really evident when you put, say, 50 buttons on a form.  You can see it paint.

Duplicating this logic is thus normal.  Using the Tag property to control state isn't.

Comment: The tag bit is checking whether the current user is supposed to be able to use the item or not.

Comment: Isn't that what Enabled/Visible is for? If the user cannot use the item, then either disable it, which Windows will render in a fairly unambiguous way, or hide it altogether. In most end-user apps, the user doesn't want to see a whole bunch of things they can't do, and neither do their supervisors (because the supervisors will invariably end up fielding requests/complaints along the lines of "why don't I have permission to do this?")

Comment: @Keith: he's using the Tag property to mean "Visible to privileged eyes only".

Comment: Exactly--the tag identifies the security attached to the function.  If they have authorization for that tag # it shows up, if they don't it doesn't show up.  The visible/disabled is basically diagnostic only.

Answer (score 0):

There is no common ancestor, however you can circumvent this by using the `dynamic` type. For example:

```
object control = new Button() { Tag = "Whatever" };
object menuItem = new ToolStripMenuItem { Tag = "Something else" };
object tag1 = (control as dynamic).Tag;
object tag2 = (menuItem as dynamic).Tag;
// Do something with tag1 and tag2
```